# Why not GOTO Statement?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c

I am doing Masters in Software Engineering. From College to University i heard from my teachers and instructors that never use GOTO statement in Programming Language.According to 
 `Software Engineering By D. Sundar`

> USE of goto statements makes a program unstructured and makes it very
>   difficult to understand.

and i also read the same in book  by MICROSOFT on its first page that never use `GOTO Statmement` in Programming.

It always arises question in my mind that if we are instructed that never use `GOTO Statement` then `why it is the part of many common programming languages` ?

Comment: Because of the Anthropic Principle: If there were no `goto` in any language, you wouldn't be seeing any warnings not to use it.

Comment: Sometimes backwards compatibility, Also some languages (such as java) have no "goto" statements at all. And there are (insanely uncommon) situations where a goto can be appropriate (which you shouldn't worry about)

Comment: `goto` is actually of crucial importance in C if you want to write arbitrary functions with multiple exits. The only way to avoid `goto` in C is to have very small functions with ad-hoc clean-up branching. If you will, C++ provides "automatic `goto`s" by means of destructors, which is why it allows you to write arbitrary code with multiple exists without looking cluttered.

Comment: Historical reasons.  If you were inventing a language from scratch today, it wouldn't have a `goto`.  But when C was being developed, it wasn't yet all that clear, and C++ has it for reasons of C compatibility.

Comment: @KerrekSB There is no case in C where a `goto` would be justified.  If you feel the need for a `goto`, then your function is probably too long and too complex.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That's what I mean by "ad-hoc code". Yes, that's a possible way of writing code, and it's pretty popular. I'm just saying, if you *want* to write arbitrary, correct functions in a systematic way, you need `goto`. You don't have to write such functions, though.

Comment: Go read Turing's Entscheidungsproblem‎ paper and see how many gotos that has. http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps210/Winter11/Papers/turing-1936.pdf

Comment: possible duplicate of [why "Using Goto" is bad programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949420/why-using-goto-is-bad-programming)

Comment: back in those assembly programming, people use to code 

label : mov ax,#65h; dec ax; 
        jnz  label;

so goto was just a replacement in c language since c was majorly developed for asm programming but as time passed, more ways has been  implemented which vanished the goto usage

Comment: There are plenty of cases in C where a goto would be justified; Knuth wrote a whole paper about it. If you're writing state machines, it's pretty much essential. (Notably, the modern language C# includes goto case and goto default to handle this.)

Comment: "c was majorly developed for asm programming" -- That's nonsense; C contains while and for loops but asm doesn't.

Comment: I wish that there was a `goto` in js. I would use ba NOW to produce a clear flow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least for some programming languages (none of which I'm the designer of, obviously) like C and C++, I imagine it's there because it

1. Closely models what the hardware really can do, which is kind of the goal in these languages.
2. Is sometimes actually useful and better than more "structured" approaches.

The most common example of when `goto` is often considered good is when doing nested error/resource management in C. See for instance the Linux kernel, a fairly large and successful C project which uses `goto` for this purpose.

Comment: yeah obviously i depends on situation and useful and better than more structired approaches. Then why i am hearing it again and again from professional people working in good organization that never use goto statement. !

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Because often it is harmful and otherwise finer points might escape teacher's attention, or be hard to explain to the students.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Because there is always a better way once you know more than one way to do something, i.e. because you have experience.

Answer (score 3):

You want to read the seminal ["Go to statement considered harmful"](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) by Edsger W. Dijkstra (1968!)

Answer (score 3):

There is no goto statement in java. The [Java keyword list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) specifies the `goto` keyword, but it is marked as "*not used*".

Answer (score 3):

You instructed not to use goto because they want to teach you how to write code. 
but sometimes goto can be useful.

when you want to break at once from a multi-level loop. you can add an exit condition to each step. and you can use goto endloop
look at this example: (psaudo code)

```
  while(cond1){
    while(cond2){
      while(cond3){
        if(want to break){
          goto endloop
        }
        do something 
        if(want to break2){
          goto endloop
        }
      }
      do something 
    }
    do something 
  }
endloop:
  do something else
```

without the goto it may look like this:

```
  while(cond1 && exitloopflag){
    while(cond2 && exitloopflag){
      while(cond3 && exitloopflag){
        if(want to break){
          exitloopflag = true;
          break;
        }
        do something 
        if(want to break2){
          exitloopflag = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(exitloopflag)
        break;
      do something     
    }
    if(exitloopflag)
      break;
    do something 
  }
  do something else
```

so we can argue which code readability is better...

Answer (score 3):

The presence of `goto` in any modern programming language is largely vestigial, sort of like the human appendix.  Its functionality has been replaced with conditional and looping control structures (if-then-else, for/while/loops, switch/case statements, etc.).  It hangs around in languages like C and C++ because there are edge cases where it's still quite useful, such as breaking out of a deeply nested loop:

```
for (...)
{
  for (...)
  {
     for(...)
     {
        ...
        // hit a fatal error, need to break out to outermost scope
        goto whoopsiedoodle;
     }
  }
}
whoopsiedoodle: 
...
```

However, its use is discouraged for a number of very good reasons: since it can branch either direction in a function, it can *destroy* the ability to debug code by simple inspection.  For example, given the following snippet:

```
       i = 1;
label: printf("i = %d\n", i);
```

What value gets printed for `i`?  How many times will that print statement be executed?  Until you account for every instance of `goto label;`, you can't know.  Now, imagine the code is structured something like the following:

```
       i = 0;
       goto label;
foo:   ...
       ...
       i = 1;
label: printf("i = %d\n", i);
       ...
       goto foo;
       ...
```

Now, imagine several dozen (or even several *hundred*) lines of code for each `...` in the snippet above.  Also imagine the presence of 10 or 11 other labels scattered throughout, with associated `goto` statements scattered largely at random.  This is modeled after some real-world code I encountered early in my career.  The only way to debug code like this is to trace the execution, line by line, accounting for every `goto` along the way.  This code was badly written to begin with (a monolithic, 5000-line `main` function, literally *hundreds* of separate variables, some declared at file scope, some local to `main`, and other atrocities), but the use of `goto` was a force amplifier that turned merely bad code into an unmaintainable sludge.  This code *defined* "brittle"; we literally could not change a single line of it without breaking something else.

Excessive use of `goto` can also hinder the compiler's ability to optimize code.  Modern compilers are quite smart, and can take advantage of structured programming techniques to do effective branch prediction or unroll loops for real performance gains.  Code like the above is almost impossible for the compiler to optimize.  That real world code that the above snippet is modeled on?  We tried to compile it with optimization flags turned on (gcc -O1).  The compiler ate all available RAM, then it ate all available swap, causing a kernel panic.

We told the customer they would either need to buy faster hardware, or allow us to rewrite the entire thing from the keel up.  They wound up buying faster hardware.

`goto` *can* be used effectively, as long as you obey the following rules:

1. Branch forward *only*.
2. Never branch into the body of a control structure (i.e., don't bypass the `if`, `for`, `while`, or `switch` condition).
3. Avoid branching over large sections of code.

Answer (score 2):

Id like to give an explanation, why you should use GOTO very carefully.

I do not say GOTO is a bad statement at all, that is one of the reasons, why it is still implemented in C++ (and due to compatibility reasons to C), in JAVA its only reserved as a keyowrd.

I can show you examples where GOTO is the best solution (in my point of view)

But you should prevent using it due to the following reason:

(Taken, translated and modified by me, from the Book [Ohne C Zu C++](http://www.buch.de/shop/home/rubrikartikel/ID2803870.html?ProvID=10910550))

> Imagine you play a game like Settlers of Catan, wherever you go, anyone has its own 
>   rules.
>   That is ok, you just need to learn the rules and then you can play with them.
>
> But what is if they will not teach u there rules, and just use it? you will loose the fun in gaming with 
>   them very fast.
>
> A goto statement is like a new Settler of Catan rule.
>
> Programming is hard enough to understand when you can reliably assume that you start at >the top, execute 1 line at a time, going down, one line at a time.
>
> Using a goto statement throws that assumption out the window, and all of the sudden, the "game! is uncertain. It's a new and uncertain rule.

Answer (score 1):

In some languages, it is used for exception handling (e.g. VBA)

Java has `goto` as a [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) but it is doing nothing. I belivie they did this, that you can't name anything `goto`

However, in some cases `goto` can be useful!

Answer (score 1):

`goto` is explicitly not allowed in Java.  It is there in other languages because it is easy to implement as it is a simple instruction in machine code, not because it is a good idea.

BTW You can do something like a goto in Java.  See if you can easily work out what this simple example does, and if you can't you are answering your own question.  If it's obvious to you what this does and how it works, you have to consider than many would find this confusing.

```
FOUND: {
    for(String s: list)
        if(s.contains(like))
             break FOUND;
    System.out.println(like + " not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Goto statements model machine code; there are very limited flow-control constructs in machine code, and there is no way to write a significant machine code program without the equivalent of a goto.

The original high-level languages, such as COBOL and FORTRAN, had Gotos because that's how people knew to control their flow from doing machine code on their machines.  The C language was also created with one, though years later, partially because that language was specifically created to be easy to compile to efficient machine code -- some of the C language constructs, such as the increment/decrement operators, are there because the machine for which C was originally created had those sub-operations in its machine code.  It can be said that C is not a high-level language, it is a structured assembler (and there's nothing wrong with that, it was ahead of its time, and still highly useful).

What Dijkstra and others figured out, though, is that (1) it isn't necessary to have a goto if you have sufficient higher-level constructs for flow control, and (2) it is horribly error-prone.  I remember reading that there were analyses of code that found that a goto statement was 9 times more likely to be in error than any other kind of statement.

It is ironic because it is not the least difficult to understand conceptually what the statement is doing; it's just that the uses programmers make of it too often turn out to make the program overall harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

*Goto* is permitted when we're jumping

- out of a scope,
- just next behind the scope close.

All other cases are invalid (jumping into a cycle, jumping into the middle of an if-block, jumping into another function, OMG, happy Halloween).

As there are several way to break a scope, like *break*, *break label*, *return* etc, there is no situation where pure *goto* must be used (except some early languages which does not support some of above, usually *break label*).

Other words, *goto* has not disappeared (it's impossible to write a program without changing the order of execution), we just make distinctions by using different keywords for different types of execution path. *Goto* now has special cases, which have own keywords. It also makes code easier to understand.